# Looking for Linux/Windows -deployable OpenGL windowing-and-OS libraries

Tags: opengl, cross-compiling

I'd like to set up an OpenGL development environment in Linux that I can also cross-compile for Windows out of.  It looks like GLFW + OpenGL will give me what I need.

I tried installing the GLFW development package for Ubuntu 8.10, but I had dependency problems.  I may stick with it, though.

Has anyone used GLFW for Linux?  Has anyone tried cross-compiling for Windows?  Is there another solution to handle windowing with OpenGL that might be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try SDL, it is very easy to use. For cross compilation, I would use MinGW or Cygwin.

Comment: Boo. SDL is simple, but slow.

Comment: @Mark: the built-in 2D drawing functions of SDL are slow, but OpenGL on SDL is not really any slower than any other library.

Answer (score 1):

I second SDL. I also suggest GLee or GLEW for extension managing as well

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at using [Qt and OpenGL](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qt-embedded-opengl.html) together for your windowing needs.  As of 4.5, Qt is now LGPL, and supports Linux, Windows, and Mac out of the box.

Comment: Also interesting, will look over Qt, too